# Which database plugin to use instead of sqlite for blackberry based phone gap app?

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova, blackberry

I am using https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin for my cordova based app and it supports android, iOS, windows OS for now.

However, we have also added blackberry OS to the app and I believe this sqlite plugin is unsupported for blackberry. As of now, the index page gets loaded in blackberry simulator and it stops there since the db does not get a call.

I am stuck at this since 3 days now and haven't found a solution yet. Could someone please provide with a solution as we only need to get over this step to publish the app successfully?

Comment: have you tried the built-in sqlite plugin i.e window.opendatabase() function call? which version of cordova are you building for?

Comment: @frank I am using cordova 3.5.0. I haven't used the built in plugin yet as the plugin I mentioned in the question has so far worked for all other platforms.

Comment: you could try the built-in plugin, as it is similar to the `brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin`. Have a look over [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

Comment: @frank I tried integrating this, however was unable to succeed. Could you help me with an example to use a db plugin for blackberry?